# How to fill data right to left in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to fill data from right to left, as data write in Urdu right to left. and i know it write from right to left. So how to do it?

Comment: Create custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, default implementation of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` does not support it.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your post. You got answers to your question: don't change the question, or it would invalidate the answers. If you have an issue with the content in your question, contact the Stack Overflow team, but don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @iDeveloper Ok, it's possible. For that, use http://stackoverflow.com/contact, ask them to delete your account and wait for instructions. But in any case, do not vandalize your posts - wait for the official response. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creation of a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` maybe is the most straight answer, but it's too expensive.
I always rather use this way (Flip the `collectionView` and it's subviews).

Inside `init` or `viewDidLoad()` put this:

```
self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
```

Inside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` or cell class put this:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
```

*EDIT*:

You can make your app completely **RTL** by doing the following:

1. Set the minimum deployment target version to iOS `9.0`
2. In your `Info.plist`, set `Localization native development region` to your RTL localization. (Like `ar_AE` for Arabic or `fa_IR` for Persian-Iran)

Comment: In the second part, instead of making transform directly on the cell, you should make transform to the contentView of the cell, like this: cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:-1,y: 1)

Answer (score 2):

swift 3

inside collection view cell

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

in viewdidload

```
self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

Comment: it does not work very well. When I rotate my iphone it's value has scaleX again and I have wrong cell's value.

Answer (score 0):

Basic `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` configurations actually have support for right-to-left layouts in iOS 9 and above... how are you running your app in RTL?

Answer (score -1):

Just click on UICollectionView in storyboard, in inspector menu under view section change semantic to Force Right-to-Left

[image of edited inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgD4i.png)